# Google Map: Dynamic Array generation javascript

Tags: javascript

Can any one please advice me, that, i need to generate an array dynamically for google map...
I have a `lat` and `long` values from my Database. here i would like to built an array with those values like...the below one.

```
var store_locations = new Array();
store_locations = [ 
     new google.maps.LatLng(39.112456,-84.574779),
     new google.maps.LatLng(39.314153,-84.261379),
     new google.maps.LatLng(39.197099,-84.667579),
     new google.maps.LatLng(39.16836,-84.479381)
   ];
```

The inner part of the square bracket should be dynamic. please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `array.push` in your cycle

```
store_locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(39.112456,-84.574779));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by pushing new elements to the array:

```
var store_locations = new Array();
store_locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(39.112456,-84.574779));
```